# Calendar spreads through variance swaps

Tags: volatility, spread-options, variance-swap

Please refer to this image from the famous paper *JUST WHAT YOU NEED TO KNOW ABOUT VARIANCE SWAPS* by Bossu et al. 2005 (page 6).

The underlined part, is there a typo?
"if the **2-year IV** is above 20.5....."
would be the correct thing, right!?[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no typo, just sloppy language.

I don't know which book this is from, but the example concerns a forward start variance swap. The forward start variance swap strike is today's expectation of future variance swap strike.

In this example, it's the expectation of the 1 year varswap strike in 1 year's time.

So if in one year's time the one year varswap strike is above/below 20.5 there will be a P/L.

Unfortunately the author starts talking about implied vols and skew and all that. So unless this example was preceded by a discussion of the Chriss-Morokoff formula which expresses the (forward start) varswap strike in terms of (forward start) implied vols , in my opinion the author could have done better.

Comment: OMG! you dared to criticize a research paper from J.P. Morgan ;)

Comment: @nbbo2 What can I say, I've never been a popular guy :) Actually, not only the wording, but also the calculation seems sloppy to me: Bossu writes 19.5x2 - 18.5 x 1, that's not even the correct units. 19.5 is vol and 2 is time, it should be variance x time or approximately vol x sqrt(T).

Comment: @Frido in simple terms does it mean that at the end of year 1, the 2year IV which is 19.5 at the inception of trade should be at 21, so the position makes half vega (21-20.5[forward IV]) .